# how do people struggling with TDD feel about leaving out the asserts?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, tdd

I've had a love/hate relationship with testing/tdd my whole career. Recenty I've started to enjoy writing tests by leaving off the assert statements. It's made all the difference in the world for me. Here's why:

- speed close to where it was when I was not writing any tests.
- i don't waste time trying to make assert(foo, 2) or !assert(foo, nil) logic at the end of each test
- I just puts foo.inspect at the end of the test, run it, and move on when it's working
- the next programmer still has a wonderful little test that shows my intent and knows this code was at one point working or it wouldn't exist.
- there's no breaking the build when tests fails because without asserts tests never fail.
- tests are not run 24/7 over and over to catch something. They are there when you want to debug some code and leave very nice notes to the next programmer (maybe you)
- there's no technical debt to pay down as years go by and tests break. The tests are always just there as archaeological relics of code that puts some useful information to the console at some point in time.

My question is, is this like a known style of testing? Because I just found it out of necessity. But are TDD people using this sytem?

Comment: _there's no breaking the build when tests fails because without asserts tests never fail._ what a point of test in this case? If new developer will make a change and want to run test to check that nothing broke - he get green test always.

Comment: "there's no breaking the build when tests fail" - imo this is one of the benefits of tests, that we have confidence to refactor and the tests tell us whether we've broken anything inadvertently.  Also for clarity of intention, having an assert statement is very helpful for the next guy (or even me when I come back to the test).  With asserts, there's less need to drop to debugging which I find much less efficient.

Comment: right but my point is those asserts take precious time to think about and author. I can fly thru my tests without them. And they end up just being technical debt after a few months. I agree it's a different way of thinking and you give up that "everything is green" feeling. But boy do I like it better.

Comment: _But are TDD people using this sytem?_ - There no TDD people which using this system - because it system simply not TDD anymore

Answer (score 1):

- speed is relative :) you are waisting time on debugging
- don't write assert if you dont' want to. test only what is needed
- no oppinion on this matter i have no clue what .inspect is
- does it or is that what comments are for
- imho a test should fail at start and you write code so it doesn't fail

  ```
  $returnVar = myClass->methodReturnsTrue();
  $this->assertTrue($returnVar);
  ```

  if you run the test without programming anything it will fail (this is    the first step)

  now write the code that make it work

  ```
  class myClass
  {
    public function methodReturnsTrue()
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  ```

  It is now fixed. the test runs and your code is tested. you can now run it over and over and over again. without it failing
- you don't have to run test 24/7 but only on code changes (new features or bug fixes) use CI for that.
- the relics make sure that your code still does what it does 20 years ago. Ofcourse on refactoring you have to rethink about the test. but in the end they make sure you don't break a feature that you have forgotten or never new that it was there in the first place

Answer (score 0):

One of the great advantages of unit tests is that once they are written they can be run automatically hundreds or thousands of time with no additional effort.

It is this that makes continuous integration so powerful. Automate the running of your tests and then run them frequently. That way when you add new code or refactor you get quick feedback if existing code has been broken.

The presence of good automated unit test coverage removes some of the fear of changing code. This encourages more frequent refactoring and often results in a better quality code base.

If you write unit tests that have to be run manually then you lose this advantage.